# Does Google offer API access to the mobile friendly test?

Tags: google-api

Is there an API that allows access to Google's Mobile Friendly Test which can be seen at https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find one by googling, it probably doesn't exist.

A hacky solution would be to create a process with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) that inputs the url, submits it, and dirty-checks the dom for results.

> PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API.

However, if you abuse this, there is a chance that google will blacklist your ip address. Light use should be fine. Also be aware that google can change their dom structure or class names at any time, so don't be surprised if your tool suddenly breaks.

Here is some rough, untested code...

```
var url = 'https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/';
page.open(url, function (status) {

  // set the url
  document.querySelector('input.jfk-textinput').value = "http://thesite.com";
  document.querySelector('form').submit();

  // check for results once in a while
  setInterval(function(){
    var results = getResults(); // TODO create getResults
    if(results){
      //TODO save the results
      phantom.exit();
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: This won't work because Google is doing a reCAPTCHA robot test on every submit.

Comment: Why not just load the page under test with PhantomJS directly, and look into the DOM to see if the page is mobile friendly.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in [pagespeed api](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v3beta1/mobileReady?url={url}&key={api key}
```

key can be obtained form google cloud platform.

Comment: api no longer work, i'm getting "not found" message.

Answer (score 0):

Acquire a PageSpeed Insights API KEY in https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/pagespeedonline-json.googleapis.com/overview?project=citric-program-395&hl=pt-br&duration=P30D and create a credentials, follow the google's instructions.

In C# (6.0) and .NET 4.5.2,  I did some like this:
(add in your project a reference for Newtonsoft.Json.)

```
String yourURL = "https://www.google.com.br";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var response = client.GetAsync($"/pagespeedonline/v3beta1/mobileReady?url={yourURL }&key=AIzaSyArsacdp79HPFfRZRvXaiLEjCD1LtDm3ww").Result;
string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
bool isMobileFriendly = obj.Value<JObject>("ruleGroups").Value<JObject>("USABILITY").Value<bool>("pass");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an API (Beta) for the Mobile Friendly-Test. (Release Date: 31.01.2017).

The API test outputs has three statuses:

1. MOBILE_FRIENDLY_TEST_RESULT_UNSPECIFIED Internal error when running this test. Please try running the test again.
2. MOBILE_FRIENDLY The page is mobile friendly.
   3.NOT_MOBILE_FRIENDLY The page is not mobile friendly.

Here are more informations: https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api/reference/rest/v1/urlTestingTools.mobileFriendlyTest/run