# Weird RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED Error (429) on Google mobile friendly test Api : Sure quota has not been reached

Tags: command-line, google-api-php-client

I searched the forum, no answer already about this.

To be precise, the API is : Google Search Console URL Testing Tools API.

Here are the limits : https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api/limits

1 query per second to resume

I have put a `sleep(1)` in my code which works quite well.

I catch the errors `429` (no more requests possible) and `502` (Server Error), in which I wait even more and try again and it does not work after an `error 502` has happened (where there is `sleep` function again).

Then I get `ERROR 429` and there are no `while catch` loops as far as I know and I don't think it is needed.

Anybody thinks of something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moreover I got it wrong the api is in beta and the quota is 1 query per 100 seconds.

Nothing weird really.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38473500/5983222 , using pagespeed api with a simple `GET` instead of a `POST` with Google PHP API Client using the mentionned API : Google Search Console URL Testing Tools API, which is still in beta at this time.